# Sql Server display decimals only if they are bigger than 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this select: `select isnull(Pricea,0)-isnull(Priceb,0) as Differences`
The format of the columns is decimal(12,4).
My question is: I could somehow to return decimals only if they are bigger than 0?
It seems to be confusing if the result will be for e.g 4.0000 so I would want to display the decimals only if they are bigger than 0. Is this possible?

Comment: All values in the column need to be of the same datatype (though that can be `sql_variant`). This is something you should sort out in your presentation layer except if you are just talking about adhoc queries in SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ceiling(Num) = floor(Num), the number is a integer

```
select case when ceiling(Num) = floor(Num) 
       then      CONVERT(varchar, CAST(Num as decimal))
       else      CONVERT(varchar, Num) 
       end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just the kind of beeing displayed in MangementStudio for the Datatypes. 
For just adapting the display kind you could do something like

```
Declare @a table  (a decimal(12,4),b decimal(12,4))
insert into @a Values(12.45,10.45)
insert into @a Values(12.45,10.4512)
insert into @a Values(12.4512,10.4500)

Select Cast(Case when a-b<>Floor(a-b) then Cast(a-b as float) else  a-b end as Varchar(30)) as Diff
from @a
```